# Como es que Firebase evita que se dupliquen los ids de los dispositivos?? Delphi 10.3.3 Multidispositivo

Tags: firebase, delphi-rio

Tengo una aplicación creada en Delphi 10.3.3 Rio, es una aplicación multidispositivo en plataforma Android que esta enfocada a crear un servicio de notificaciones Push con Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Al compilar la aplicación en un dispositivo Android, se abre la aplicacion y muestra un memo con el **DeviceID: 7DAGSEKD87SU2764C9AJ2SD3854743218** y el FireBase Token: sfsaksxxxxxxxxx

**DeviceID** := **Es el id del dispositivo, el cual esta enfocada mi pregunta, como es que firebase, evita que se dupliquen estas ids(DeviceID) de los dispositivos?? o bien como es que se esta obteniendo este token del dispositivo??.**

He realizado pruebas en diferentes dispositivos android y cada DeviceID es diferente.

Dejo el siguiente codigo, ya que es el que hace todo el proceso para la obtencion del DeviceID.

```
    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
   PushService: TPushService;
   ServiceConnection: TPushServiceConnection;
   Notifications: TArray<TPushServiceNotification>;
begin
   PushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.GCM);
   ServiceConnection := TPushServiceConnection.Create(PushService);
   ServiceConnection.Active := True;
   ServiceConnection.OnChange := OnServiceConnectionChange;
   ServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification := OnReceiveNotificationEvent;

   FDeviceId := PushService.DeviceIDValue[TPushService.TDeviceIDNames.DeviceId];
   MemoLog.Lines.Add('DeviceID: ' + FDeviceId);
   MemoLog.Lines.Add('Ready to receive!');

   // Checks notification on startup, if application was launched fromcold start
   // by tapping on Notification in Notification Center
   Notifications := PushService.StartupNotifications;
   if Length(Notifications) > 0 then
   begin
       MemoLog.Lines.Add('-----------------------------------------');
       MemoLog.Lines.Add('DataKey = ' + Notifications[0].DataKey);
       MemoLog.Lines.Add('Json = ' + Notifications[0].Json.ToString);
       MemoLog.Lines.Add('DataObject = ' +
 Notifications[0].DataObject.ToString);
       MemoLog.Lines.Add('-----------------------------------------');
   end;
end;
```

Para realizar esto, me he guiado del siguiente link: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Firebase_Android_Support

Answer (score 0):

En Firebase existe un concepto llamado unique keys, en el cual son llaves alfanumericas generadas automaticamente por Firebase, estas claves son generadas con un timestamp del momento en las que fueron creadas, por lo cual aseguran que sean totalmente unicas ya que no se pueden generar dos claves con la misma marca de tiempo, adicionalmente a esta marca de tiempo se agregan caracteres alphanumericos para asegurar aun mas la unicidad.

Tu linea

```
  FDeviceId := PushService.DeviceIDValue[TPushService.TDeviceIDNames.DeviceId];
```

Crea exactamente una clave unica por dispositivo con el mismo concepto

Podes chequear este artículo que explica exactamente como funciona

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html